# Clicking a checkbox to an app using a script

Tags: applications, scripts

I need to automate accepting a terms & conditions on a 3rd party app installed on the Android device. I just need to click a checkbox on that app's T&C UI. Can someone please guide me how I can do that? I assume I need to write a script??

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate touch event with an `adb` command: `adb shell input tap <x> <y>`, where x and y are the coordinates of your checkbox.

More about `input`:

```
$ input
input
usage: input ...
       input text <string>
       input keyevent <key code number or name>
       input [touchscreen|touchpad|touchnavigation] tap <x> <y>
       input [touchscreen|touchpad|touchnavigation] swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2> [duration(ms)]
       input trackball press
       input trackball roll <dx> <dy>
```

To the `adb` you have to enable `Developer settings` on your device and accept your computer's fingerprint.

With this you can write a script to tap on the box.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please provide me some hints to find the coordinates of the checkbox on a running app? I assume I need to run the same app off of Android Studio on a simulator or are there any easier way to find it?

Comment: Go to `Settings` -> `Developer Options` -> enable `Pointer location` than profit.